# Display item from a listbox in msgbox

Tags: vb.net

I would like my code to search through a listbox looking for "QB". Once found display message then stop. Write now my code continues to search through the listbox after. How can i change the way that i am searching the listbox?

```
Private Sub btnQB_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnQB.Click
　
For i As Integer = 0 To lstPlayers.Items.Count - 1

    Dim txt = lstPlayers.Items(i).ToString()

      If txt.Contains("QB") Then

           MessageBox.Show(lstPlayers.Items(i))

      Else
           MessageBox.Show("No Listed Quaterbacks")
　
End If

Next
```

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
dim bFound as Boolean = false 
For i As Integer = 0 To lstPlayers.Items.Count - 1

  Dim txt = lstPlayers.Items(i).ToString()

  If txt.Contains("QB") Then
     bFound = true 
     MessageBox.Show(lstPlayers.Items(i))
     return
  End If

Next

if not bFound Then
  MessageBox.Show("No Listed Quaterbacks") 　 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
Dim SB As New System.Text.StringBuilder

        For Each Item As String In ListBox1.Items

            SB.Append(Item & vbCrLf)

        Next

        MessageBox.Show(SB.ToString)
```